# chrome ui issues with mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, gtk, qt

I did install Mint 17 (Qiana) today and I seem to have problems with the window title bars such as chromium title bar. I have limited knowledge of tool kits such as qt or gtk.

From what I read so far, they seem to be two libraries/framework satisfying the same purpose. so on a system with one desktop environment such as gnome, I believe there should be only one framework installed gtk in this case?

Or is there a problem with the window manager?

I was trying to install virtualbox but I found only virtualbox-qt, but later I uninstalled the package and purged conf files.

Is it normal that I see a lot of other qt libraries installed on the system?

*gtk libraries*:

```
ii  gir1.2-gtk-3.0                              3.10.8~3+qiana                                      amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface library -- gir bindings
ii  gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0                       1.4.4-3ubuntu2                                      amd64        GObject introspection data for the GTK+ Clutter library
ii  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0                        3.10.2-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        gir files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0                2.4.0-1ubuntu2                                      amd64        JavaScript engine library from WebKitGTK+ - GObject introspection data
ii  gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0                            0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.1-mint1                            amd64        GObject introspection data for libnm-gtk
ii  gtk2-engines:amd64                          1:2.20.2-3ubuntu1                                   amd64        theme engines for GTK+ 2.x
ii  gtk2-engines:i386                           1:2.20.2-3ubuntu1                                   i386         theme engines for GTK+ 2.x
ii  gtk2-engines-murrine:amd64                  0.98.2-0ubuntu2                                     amd64        cairo-based gtk+-2.0 theme engine
ii  gtk2-engines-murrine:i386                   0.98.2-0ubuntu2                                     i386         cairo-based gtk+-2.0 theme engine
ii  gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386                    1.4.5-0ubuntu1                                      i386         Oxygen widget theme for GTK+-based applications
ii  gtk2-engines-pixbuf:amd64                   2.24.23-0ubuntu1                                    amd64        pixbuf-based theme for GTK+ 2.x
ii  gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386                    2.24.23-0ubuntu1                                    i386         pixbuf-based theme for GTK+ 2.x
ii  ibus-gtk:i386                               1.5.5-1ubuntu3                                      i386         Intelligent Input Bus - GTK+2 support
ii  libcanberra-gtk-module:i386                 0.30-0ubuntu3                                       i386         translates GTK+ widgets signals to event sounds
ii  libcanberra-gtk0:amd64                      0.30-0ubuntu3                                       amd64        GTK+ helper for playing widget event sounds with libcanberra
ii  libcanberra-gtk0:i386                       0.30-0ubuntu3                                       i386         GTK+ helper for playing widget event sounds with libcanberra
ii  libcanberra-gtk3-0:amd64                    0.30-0ubuntu3                                       amd64        GTK+ 3.0 helper for playing widget event sounds with libcanberra
ii  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0:amd64                  1.4.4-3ubuntu2                                      amd64        Open GL based interactive canvas library GTK+ widget
ii  libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:amd64                    12.10.3+14.04.20140319-0ubuntu1                     amd64        library for passing menus over DBus - GTK+ version
ii  libdbusmenu-gtk4:amd64                      12.10.3+14.04.20140319-0ubuntu1                     amd64        library for passing menus over DBus - GTK+ version
ii  libgtk-3-0:amd64                            3.10.8~3+qiana                                      amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-bin                                3.10.8~3+qiana                                      amd64        programs for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-common                             3.10.8~3+qiana                                      all          common files for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-sharp-beans-cil                      2.14.1-3                                            all          Supplementary CLI bindings for GTK 2.14+
ii  libgtk2-perl                                2:1.249-2                                           amd64        Perl interface to the 2.x series of the Gimp Toolkit library
ii  libgtk2.0-0:amd64                           2.24.23-0ubuntu1                                    amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-0:i386                            2.24.23-0ubuntu1                                    i386         GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-bin                               2.24.23-0ubuntu1                                    amd64        programs for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-cil                               2.12.10-5                                           amd64        CLI binding for the GTK+ toolkit 2.12
ii  libgtk2.0-common                            2.24.23-0ubuntu1                                    all          common files for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtkglext1                                1.2.0-3.1fakesync3                                  amd64        OpenGL Extension to GTK+ (shared libraries)
ii  libgtkmm-3.0-1:amd64                        3.10.1-0ubuntu2                                     amd64        C++ wrappers for GTK+ (shared libraries)
ii  libgtksourceview-3.0-1:amd64                3.10.2-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        shared libraries for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  libgtksourceview-3.0-common                 3.10.2-0ubuntu1                                     all          common files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  libgtksourceview2.0-0                       2.10.5-1ubuntu2                                     amd64        shared libraries for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  libgtksourceview2.0-common                  2.10.5-1ubuntu2                                     all          common files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
ii  libgtkspell0                                2.0.16-1ubuntu7                                     amd64        a spell-checking addon for GTK's TextView widget
ii  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0:amd64            2.4.0-1ubuntu2                                      amd64        JavaScript engine library from WebKitGTK+
ii  libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0:amd64            2.4.0-1ubuntu2                                      amd64        JavaScript engine library from WebKitGTK+
ii  libnm-gtk-common                            0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.1-mint1                            all          network management framework (common files for wifi and mobile)
ii  libnm-gtk0                                  0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.1-mint1                            amd64        network management framework (GNOME dialogs for wifi and mobile)
ii  libreoffice-gtk                             1:4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2                                amd64        office productivity suite -- GTK+ integration
ii  libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25:amd64                  2.4.0-1ubuntu2                                      amd64        WebKit2 API layer for WebKitGTK+
ii  libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64                    2.4.0-1ubuntu2                                      amd64        Web content engine library for GTK+
ii  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common                     2.4.0-1ubuntu2                                      all          Web content engine library for GTK+ - data files
ii  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64                    2.4.0-1ubuntu2                                      amd64        Web content engine library for GTK+
ii  libwebkitgtk-3.0-common                     2.4.0-1ubuntu2                                      all          Web content engine library for GTK+ - data files
ii  mint-themes-gtk3                            3.10-5                                              all          Mint themes for GTK3
ii  python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets                1.1.1-1ubuntu5                                      all          Python 2 GTK+ 3 widgets to run an aptdaemon client
ii  python-gtk2                                 2.24.0-3ubuntu3                                     amd64        Python bindings for the GTK+ widget set
ii  python-gtksourceview2                       2.10.1-2build1                                      amd64        Python bindings for the GtkSourceView widget
ii  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets               1.1.1-1ubuntu5                                      all          Python 3 GTK+ 3 widgets to run an aptdaemon client
ii  transmission-gtk                            2.82-1.1ubuntu3                                     amd64        lightweight BitTorrent client (GTK+ interface)
ii  xdg-user-dirs-gtk                           0.10-1ubuntu1                                       amd64        tool to manage well known user directories (Gtk extension)
```

*qt libraries*:

```
ii  libaccounts-qt5-1                           1.11+14.04.20140410.1-0ubuntu1                      amd64        QT library for single sign on
ii  libdbusmenu-qt2:amd64                       0.9.3+14.04.20140314-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Qt implementation of the DBusMenu protocol
ii  libqt4-dbus:amd64                           4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 D-Bus module
ii  libqt4-dbus:i386                            4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 D-Bus module
ii  libqt4-declarative:amd64                    4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 Declarative module
ii  libqt4-declarative:i386                     4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 Declarative module
ii  libqt4-designer:amd64                       4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 designer module
ii  libqt4-designer:i386                        4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 designer module
ii  libqt4-help:amd64                           4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 help module
ii  libqt4-network:amd64                        4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 network module
ii  libqt4-network:i386                         4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 network module
ii  libqt4-opengl:amd64                         4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 OpenGL module
ii  libqt4-opengl:i386                          4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 OpenGL module
ii  libqt4-qt3support:i386                      4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 3 compatibility library for Qt 4
ii  libqt4-script:amd64                         4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 script module
ii  libqt4-script:i386                          4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 script module
ii  libqt4-scripttools:amd64                    4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 script tools module
ii  libqt4-scripttools:i386                     4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 script tools module
ii  libqt4-sql:amd64                            4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 SQL module
ii  libqt4-sql:i386                             4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 SQL module
ii  libqt4-svg:amd64                            4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 SVG module
ii  libqt4-svg:i386                             4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 SVG module
ii  libqt4-test:amd64                           4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 test module
ii  libqt4-test:i386                            4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 test module
ii  libqt4-xml:amd64                            4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 XML module
ii  libqt4-xml:i386                             4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 XML module
ii  libqt4-xmlpatterns:amd64                    4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 XML patterns module
ii  libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386                     4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 XML patterns module
ii  libqt5core5a:amd64                          5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14                                amd64        Qt 5 core module
ii  libqt5dbus5:amd64                           5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14                                amd64        Qt 5 D-Bus module
ii  libqt5gui5:amd64                            5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14                                amd64        Qt 5 GUI module
ii  libqt5network5:amd64                        5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14                                amd64        Qt 5 network module
ii  libqt5opengl5:amd64                         5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14                                amd64        Qt 5 OpenGL module
ii  libqt5positioning5:amd64                    5.2.1-1ubuntu2                                      amd64        Qt Positioning module
ii  libqt5printsupport5:amd64                   5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14                                amd64        Qt 5 print support module
ii  libqt5qml5:amd64                            5.2.1-3ubuntu15                                     amd64        Qt 5 QML module
ii  libqt5quick5:amd64                          5.2.1-3ubuntu15                                     amd64        Qt 5 Quick library
ii  libqt5sensors5:amd64                        5.2.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2                                 amd64        Qt Sensors module
ii  libqt5sql5:amd64                            5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14                                amd64        Qt 5 SQL module
ii  libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64                     5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14                                amd64        Qt 5 SQLite 3 database driver
ii  libqt5test5:amd64                           5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14                                amd64        Qt 5 test module
ii  libqt5webkit5:amd64                         5.1.1-1ubuntu8                                      amd64        Web content engine library for Qt
ii  libqt5widgets5:amd64                        5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14                                amd64        Qt 5 widgets module
ii  libqt5xml5:amd64                            5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14                                amd64        Qt 5 XML module
ii  libqtassistantclient4:amd64                 4.6.3-6                                             amd64        Qt Assistant client library (runtime)
ii  libqtcore4:amd64                            4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 core module
ii  libqtcore4:i386                             4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 core module
ii  libqtdbus4:amd64                            4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 D-Bus module library
ii  libqtdbus4:i386                             4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 D-Bus module library
ii  libqtgui4:amd64                             4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               amd64        Qt 4 GUI module
ii  libqtgui4:i386                              4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               i386         Qt 4 GUI module
ii  libqtwebkit4:amd64                          2.3.2-0ubuntu7                                      amd64        Web content engine library for Qt
ii  libqtwebkit4:i386                           2.3.2-0ubuntu7                                      i386         Web content engine library for Qt
ii  libsignon-qt5-1                             8.56+14.04.20140307-0ubuntu2                        amd64        Single Sign On framework
ii  python-qt4                                  4.10.4+dfsg-1ubuntu1                                amd64        Python bindings for Qt4
ii  python-qt4-dbus                             4.10.4+dfsg-1ubuntu1                                amd64        D-Bus Support for PyQt4
ii  qt-at-spi:amd64                             0.3.1-4fakesync1                                    amd64        at-spi accessibility plugin for Qt
ii  qtchooser                                   39-g4717841-3                                       amd64        Wrapper to select between Qt development binary versions
ii  qtcore4-l10n                                4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4               all          Qt 4 core module translations
ii  sni-qt:amd64                                0.2.6-0ubuntu1                                      amd64        indicator support for Qt
```

[image: chromium title bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems absolutely normal to have those packages installed. On my system Mint 17 system I have the same.

If you think there are libraries left that are no longer needed you can always issue a:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

to get rid of them, but I guess that will not bring you anything.

If you have `apt-rdepends` installed you can can use:

```
apt-rdepends -r --state-follow=Installed --state-show=Installed libqtdbus4
```

to see what (reverse) dependencies for an installed package on your system. (You can also use `apt-get remove packagename` and then abort the action as a primitive alternative for seeking out dependencies).

From the above `apt-rdepends` invocation it looks like `vlc` is the program that is installed by default and requires the qt libraries.

Comment: thanks for your comments. i can also confirm the most of the qt packages have been installed because of vlc. i can understand a handful of qt libraries may not be a problem. but would you recommend installing kde applications on a gnome desktop environment; would it not cause conflicts with packages that came with gnome apps? by the way, do you have title bar problems with the chromium `Version 34.0.1847.116 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on LinuxMint 17 aura (260972)` ?

Comment: @rag I have been using vlc under Ubuntu for years, as well as other KDE applications when the Ubuntu version did not please me. In those 8+ years I never found a problem with having Qt installed, that is why I use a distribution, so that all those things just work (at the expense of not having always the latest version of an app).

Comment: hi, what do you mean by "so that all those things just work (at the expense of not having always the latest version of an app)"

Comment: @rag Sometimes Ubuntu, for compatibility or maintenance reasons, just doesn't have the latest version of some software. And if you use a LTS release like Ubuntu 12.04 you don't have the latest/greatest, but it all works together.